# Dispelling (un)hallow linked spells

Tags: spells, dnd-3e

Both in 3e and 3.5e D&D, the [*Hallow*](http://www.zombler.org/files/srd30a/spellsh.htm) and [*Unhallow*](http://www.zombler.org/files/srd30a/spellsuvwxyz.htm) spells are instantaneous spells and, as such, they cannot be dispelled in any way.

While they are active, they can also radiate a single spell from a small list, which lasts as long as the *(un)hallow* spell is active.
It is not clearly specified if this spell is to be considered instantaneous or lasting.

What would happen if an area dispel is cast in an overlapping area? (I'm thinking about temporary suppression of the linked spell but I'm not sure)
Is there any difference if the area includes the *(un)hallow* altar or not?

**While a 3e answer is required, I'd appreciate mentioning if the answer would be different in 3.5e.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spell afixed to the (*un*) *hallow* spell has a duration of 1 year, rather than Instantaneous.

> The spell effect lasts for one year [...] regardless of the normal duration

The second part of this clause makes it clear that the time of one year counts as a duration. As such, it may be dispelled as if it were a normal spell with a duration of 1 year (and an area equal to that of the (*un*) *hallow* effect, so an area dispel needs to include the center of the (*un*) *hallow* effect).

This does nothing, of course, to the underlying (*un*) *hallow* effect, since that was Instantaneous. Another casting of (*un*) *hallow* would be necessary to replace the dispelled effect, just as if its duration (of 1 year) had lapsed.